# How to split and parse particular value of json array using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json

How can i `split` and `parse` particular `json` data using `angularjs`.

My `json` is

```
 [{"id":"1", "stud":" name=Alex, roll_no=12 | class=12,sec=1" , "tech":"Sam"},
  {"id":"2", "stud":" name=john, roll_no=13 | class=12,sec=2" , "tech":"Sandy"},
  {"id":"3", "stud":" name=Cate, roll_no=14 | class=12,sec=1" , "tech":"Sandy"},
 ]
```

I want to parse this json formated data like if  **ID =1** .

Name= Alex.
Roll No=12.
Class=12.
Section=1.
Teacher=Sam.

Comment: want to fetch data, i know about ng-if and ng-repeat, here i am unable to split and indexof using angular.

Comment: use angular foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the collection with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
On every Object in the collection parse the `stud` attribute with [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Create the new string and add it to the new collection.

```
// Pseudocode
collection.reduce((memo, item) => {
    const values = item.stud.match(" name=Alex, roll_no=12 | class=12,sec=1".match(/^ name=(\w*), roll_no=(\d{2}).../))
    // Add it to memo in a format you like
    return memo
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote you some functions...

```
function getRowFromJson(json, id){
   for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++) 
     if('undefined' == json[i].id) continue;
     else if(json[i].id==id) return json[i];
   return false;
}

function parseStudFromRow(row){
  var stud = {};
  var chunks = row.stud.split("|");
  for(var i=0; i<chunks.length; i++){
    var morechunks = chunks[i].split(",");
    for(var n=0; n<morechunks.length; n++){
      var chunkage = morechunks[n].split("=");
      stud[chunkage[0].trim()] = chunkage[1].trim();
    }
  }
  return stud;
}
```

You use it like this..

```
var row = getRowFromJson(json, 1);
var stud = parseStudFromRow(row);
console.log(stud);
```

Check out the example.. https://jsfiddle.net/o0v6nyzu/2/

Comment: i want same thing but how can use in html tag like, i am showing data using ng-repeat,,,,, {{s.stud}}  , {{s.teach}}.....   i need to filter overhere in {{s.stud}}. Please tell how can i use ur sollution overhere inside {{s.stud}}.

Comment: i have no idea, sorry, not familiar with angular. maybe someone smarter than me can tell you how to create what you want with the object provided.